# how to use Linq groupby and where with date conditions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, dapper

I'm trying to use Linq groupby and where with date conditions in vb.net

Please Guide Me.

PIQ is total purchase quantity

SIQ is total sales quantity

BLC is total purchase quantity minus total sales quantity

Thanks

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Purchase, Sales As New List(Of Invoice)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub
    Private PurchaseDetails,SalesDetails As New List(Of Detail)
    Private Function CreateConnection() As String
        Return ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function
Private Sub LoadData()
        Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
 Purchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM PURCHASE"), List(Of Invoice))
            PurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PURCHASEDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
 Sales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM SALES"), List(Of Invoice))
            SalesDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SALESDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
End Using
        Dim ps = From p In Purchase
                 Where p.DATEINVO >= CDate("01/01/2024")
                 From pd In PurchaseDetails
                 Select
             pd.ITEM,
             PIQ = pd.QTY,
             SIQ = 0,
             BLC = pd.QTY
                 Order By ITEM
        Dim ss = From s In Sales
                 Where s.DATEINVO >= CDate("01/01/2024")
                 From sd In SalesDetails
                 Select
            sd.ITEM,
            PIQ = 0,
            SIQ = sd.QTY,
            BLC = -sd.QTY
                 Order By ITEM
 Dim Card_temp = ps.Union(ss).OrderBy(Function(w) w.ITEM)
 Dim Card As New List(Of ItemCards3)
        Dim RunningBalance As Integer = 0
        For Each ct In Card_temp
            Dim sc As New ItemCards3
            With sc
                .ITEM = ct.ITEM
                .PIQ = ct.PIQ
                .SIQ = ct.SIQ
                .BLC = ct.PIQ - ct.SIQ
                '.BLC = RunningBalance + ct.BLC
                'RunningBalance = .BLC
            End With
            Card.Add(sc)
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Card
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Invoice
    Property INVONO() As String
    Property DATEINVO() As Date
    Property CUSTCODE() As String
End Class

Public Class Detail
    Public Property INVONO() As String
    Public Property NOD() As Integer
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property QTY() As Integer
End Class
Public Class ItemCards3
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property PIQ As Integer
    Public Property SIQ As Integer
    Public Property BLC As Integer
End Class
```

Table `PURCHASE`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PI1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| PI1001 | 29-Jan-23 | 002 |
| PI1002 | 29-Jan-24 | 003 |
| PI0003 | 30-Jan-24 | 004 |

Table `PURCHASEDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PI1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| PI1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| PI1001 | 1 | TEST 3000 | 15 |
| PI1002 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 20 |
| PI1003 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 15 |

Table `SALES`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SI1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| SI1001 | 29-Jan-23 | 002 |
| SI1002 | 29-Jan-24 | 005 |
| SI1003 | 30-Jan-24 | 006 |
| SI1004 | 29-Jan-24 | 004 |
| SI1005 | 30-Jan-24 | 003 |

Table `SALESDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| SI1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| SI1001 | 1 | TEST 8000 | 35 |
| SI1002 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 27 |
| SI1003 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 15 |
| SI1004 | 1 | TEST 2000 | 2 |
| SI1005 | 1 | TEST 2000 | 2 |

the result of the code above

| ITEM | PIQ | SIQ | BLC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 15 | 0 | 15 |
| TEST 1000 | 10 | 0 | 25 |
| TEST 1000 | 20 | 0 | 45 |
| TEST 1000 | 0 | 10 | 35 |
| TEST 1000 | 0 | 27 | 8 |
| TEST 1000 | 0 | 15 | -7 |
| TEST 2000 | 20 | 0 | 13 |
| TEST 2000 | 0 | 20 | -7 |
| TEST 2000 | 0 | 2 | -9 |
| TEST 3000 | 15 | 0 | 6 |
| TEST 8000 | 0 | 35 | -29 |

Desired result

| ITEM | PIQ | SIQ | BLC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 35 | 42 | -7 |
| TEST 2000 |  | 4 | -4 |

result from answer @TN

[image: update result answer code]

result after update answer form @TN

[image: result after update answer form @TN]

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before using it and only use it if it is relevant to the question. You're using an Access database so obviously the LINQ to SQL tag can't be relevant, given that it is specific to SQL Server. I don't use Dapper so I could be wrong but your use of `Connection.Query` looks like you're using Dapper to me, but you don't have a Dapper tag. Either way, you need to pay more attention to your tags and keep them relevant.

Comment: I would suggest you: (1) Fix your code indentation so that it is more readable. The current posted code indentation is a ragged mess. Adding code comments describing what block of code is doing would be a plus. (2) Describe what it is that the code is attempting to accomplish and what the meaning of the data elements. Specifically, what are PIQ, SIQ, and BLQ? (3) Describe where you believe you are having problems. "Please Guide Me" is not a focused question.

Comment: @TN , Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated the description as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is that your Purchase/PurchaseDetails query is referencing both tables, but is not providing a join condition. This will result in a cross join where every Purchase row joins to every PurchaseDetails row. The same applied to the Sales/SalesDetails query.

I believe this can be corrected using the following `Join ... On ...` LINQ syntax.

```
Dim ps = From p In Purchase
         Where p.DATEINVO >= CDate("01/01/2024")
         Join pd In PurchaseDetails On pd.INVONO Equals p.INVONO
         Select
             pd.ITEM,
             PIQ = pd.QTY,
             SIQ = 0,
             BLC = pd.QTY
         Order By ITEM
Dim ss = From s In Sales
         Where s.DATEINVO >= CDate("01/01/2024")
         Join sd In SalesDetails On sd.INVONO Equals s.INVONO
         Select
             sd.ITEM,
             PIQ = 0,
             SIQ = sd.QTY,
             BLC = -sd.QTY
         Order By ITEM
```

Once you have those two queries defined, you can combine, group, and calculate the resulting sums with a combination of `.Concat()`, `.GroupBy()`, `.Select()`, and `.Sum()`. Within the `.Select()`, the group-by `ITEM` value is accessed via the grouping `.Key` property, while the other values are calculated using `.Sum()` to iterate through the members of each grouping.

The `.Concat()` function is used instead of `.Union()` because we do *not* want to eliminate duplicates. The `.Concat()` function unconditionally includes all rows.

The result would be something like:

```
Dim Card_temp = ps.Concat(ss) _
    .GroupBy(Function(w) w.ITEM) _
    .Select(Function(g) New ItemCards3 With {
        .ITEM = g.Key,
        .PIQ = g.Sum(Function(m) m.PIQ),
        .SIQ = g.Sum(Function(m) m.SIQ),
        .BLC = g.Sum(Function(m) m.BLC)
    }) _
    .OrderBy(Function(ic) ic.ITEM) _
    .ToList()
```

or

```
Dim Card_temp = (From w In ps.Concat(ss)
                 Group By w.ITEM Into g
                 Select New ItemCards3 With {
                     .ITEM = g.ITEM,
                     .PIQ = g.Sum(Function(m) m.PIQ),
                     .SIQ = g.Sum(Function(m) m.SIQ),
                     .BLC = g.Sum(Function(m) m.BLC)
                 }
                 Order By ITEM
                ) _
                .ToList()
```

The `.OrderBy()` and `.ToList()` are present to organize the results.

*Note: I am a C# programmer, not a VB programmer, so I prepared the above code snippets in C# and translated to VB with the assistance of a translator tool. Not sure if I have the syntax exactly right - particularly with respect to required vs optional line continuations characters*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I have an error for line this code `Join pd In PurchaseDetails On pd.INVONO = p.INVONO` and `Join sd In SalesDetails On sd.INVONO = s.INVONO` `Error BC36619 'Equals' expected` .

Comment: Yes the "=" should be "Equals". I have updated my answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your update.  For this code `Dim Card_temp = ps.Union(ss) _` , use the first option . Second option there is an error.
I have posted the results of your answer.  So from item `TEST 1000` in PIQ should be valuable `35` and `TEST 2000`  in SIQ should be valuable `4`

Comment: A @siwa86 - I have updated the above answer to use `.Concat()` instead of `.Union()`. This should fix the erroneous 2 vs the expected 4 in the result. I do not understand why you are getting a 20 instead of the expected 35 for Test 2000 SIQ, or the -24 Test 2000 BLQ value. PLease double check your data.

Comment: Thank you for your update, for `BLC` value 
I've updated the code to: `.BLC = ct.PIQ - ct.SIQ` and for option 1 answer  
still a little more and not quite right for item `TEST 1000` in PIQ should be valuable `35`.  I also tried option 2 of your answer but there was an error `Definition of method 'g' is not accessible in this context` and `Name 'ITEM' is either not declared or not in the current scope`

Comment: `PI0003` This is the problem error in `INVONO` in table `PURCHASE` So your answer is correct for option 1, so sorry I have a late response to you